# Replace part of a cell formula dynamically using value of another cell

Tags: python, vba, excel

I'm having a hard time formatting a spreadsheet... maybe you guys can help me.

I need to replace part of a formula in aprox. 1700 cells.

The original formula present in each of these cells respects the following format:

```
='2014-12'!$F$7
```

I'm interested in replacing the `'2014-12'` part of the formula with the value of the cell in the first row of each colum. Note that the `$F$7` part changes in each cell.

**Ex.:**

[image]

As you can see, the first row of my spreadsheet contains the year that I must replace inside the formulas that are written in the cells right above the year.

**Data goes from:**

- row 5 to 96 (not every cell in the column contains formulas)
- column 2 to 25

My first idea was to use python to achieve this... but I couldn't make it work with `pyoo`, `oosheet` or `uno`. So I came to `Excel` and was trying to write a macro that does the following:

**Macro Idea:**

1. for column i = 2 to 25,
2. get `Cell(1, i).Value`,
3. for row j = 5 to 96,
4. get `Cell(j, i).Formula`
5. replace the '2014-12' part in `Cell(j, i).Formula`, with `Cell(1, i).Value`
6. done

[image]

---

**My code so far:**

```
Sub replace_content_of_formula()

Dim i, j As Integer

For i = 2 To 25
    year = Cells(1, i).Value

    For j = 5 To 96
        prev_formula = Cells(j, i).Formula
        new_formula = prev_formula[:2] & year & prev_formula[9:] <<< I DONT KNOW HOW TO DO THIS
        Cells(j, i).Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = new_formula <<< I DONT KNOW HOW TO DO THIS

    Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

I would appreciate any help.

Ps.: I can use `python` or `vba`.

Comment: Hi. Can you please specify how is the *Cell Reference* changing? `='Sheet Reference'!Cell Reference`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main thing you needed to learn was the existence of the `Mid` function, or the `Replace` function.  Revised code is as follows:

```
Sub replace_content_of_formula()
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim prev_formula As String
    Dim new_formula As String
    Dim YearValue As String

    For i = 2 To 25
        YearValue = Cells(1, i).Value

        For j = 5 To 96
            prev_formula = Cells(j, i).FormulaR1C1
            new_formula = Replace(prev_formula, "2014-12", YearValue)
            'Or
            'new_formula = Mid(prev_formula, 1, 2) & YearValue & Mid(prev_formula, 10)
            Cells(j, i).FormulaR1C1 = new_formula
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not at a computer with Windows installed, but this is working in LibreOffice Calc...

If you write, in cell A5, `=A$1`, it will (obviously) refer to A1. If you copy and paste this over your sheet, it will be pasted as `=B$1` in column B, `=C$1` in column C etc. So it will always look up the first row.

If the first row is formatted dates rather than text, they can be converted to text using `=Text(C$1, "YYYY-MM")` to match the sheet names.

Next we can write the address of the cell on the other sheet using the `Address` function.

`=Address(1, 1, 4, True, Text(C$1, "YYYY-MM"))` will produce the *text* `'2015-12'!A1`

```
=Address(1, // the row
         1, // the column
         4, // absolute or relative format. A number from 1 to 4. 4 is relative row & relative column
         True, // A1 or R1C1 format. True is A1
         Text(C$1, "YYYY-MM") // the sheet name
         )
```

If we use the `Row()` and `Column()` functions for the first two arguments the output of `Address` will refer to the same cell on another sheet:

`=Address(Row(), Column(), 4, True, Text(C$1, "YYYY-MM"))` will produce `'2015-12'!C5` in cell C5.

You can then add the offsets by adding to `Row()` and `Column()` - hopefully these offsets are the same for all the cells you're looking up!

`=Address(Row() + 2, Column() + 3, 4, True, Text(C$1, "YYYY-MM"))` will produce `'2015-12'!F7` in cell C5.

Finally, turn the text from `Address` into a lookup using the `Indirect` function:

`=Indirect(Address(Row() + 2, Column() + 3, 4, True, Text(C$1, "YYYY-MM")))`

You should then be able to copy-paste this formula over your sheet.

Comment: You are on the right track, but the formula returns a #REF! error, due to the fact, that the `F7` cell is not in quotation marks. This works `=INDIRECT("'" & C$1 & "'!F7")`, with one catch. OP said that the `F7` part is variable.

Comment: Great idea. This should work. `=INDIRECT("'" & C$1 & "'!" & ADDRESS(7;6;1;1))`. The OP should decide, how the `row_num` and `column_num` arguments change. Than use for example `ROWS` or `COLUMNS` function as argument values.